# jQuery if each input value inside each li == 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to solve this issue. I have multiple inputs and I would like to compare if everyone has value == 0 and is also checked.

I don't know how to do it - I spend almost day searching and finding a way how to do it and don't have clue how to go further. I tried to find if one input is checked and has that value.

Thank U for Your help.

```js
$(document).on('change','select, input', function() {
  console.log('input/select has been changed');
  
  var $this = $(this);
  var $inputValue = $this.val();
  
  console.log('input Value is ' + $inputValue);
  
  if ($inputValue == 0 && $this.is(':checked')) {
    console.log('One input is checked and has 0 value');
  }
  
  if ('all first inputs are checked and has 0 value') {
    console.warn('Could U help me?');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="destinations">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="destination" value="0">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="destination" value="5">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="destination" value="3">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="languages">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="language" value="0">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="language" value="5">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="language" value="3">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div class="rooms">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="0">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="5">
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="3">
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: have a read of this: https://api.jquery.com/each/
You will be able to use $(this).val() per interrelation and get the val of the element

Comment: Can you be more specific about your goal. It sounds like you want to validate that all three groups of inputs have a selection made, and that it's not on the `0` value - is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want, but I think this can help you

```js
 $(document).on('change', 'select, input', function () {
                console.log('input/select has been changed');
                checkInputValue();

            });
            
            function checkInputValue() {
                var inputs = $('input');
                var inputsWithValZero = $(inputs).filter(function (index,elm) {                
                    return ($(elm).val() == 0);
                });
                
                var inputsWithValZeroAndChecked = $(inputs).filter(function (index,elm) {                
                    return ($(elm).val() == 0 && $(elm).is(':checked'));
                });
                            
                if ($(inputsWithValZero).length == inputsWithValZeroAndChecked.length){
                    console.log('all checked inputs checked has 0 value');
                    }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <div class="destinations">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="destination" value="0">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="destination" value="5">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="destination" value="3">
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="languages">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="language" value="0">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="language" value="5">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="language" value="3">
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <div class="rooms">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="0">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="5">
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="room" value="3">
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank U thats it! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        $(document).on('change', 'select, input', function () {
            console.log('input/select has been changed');
            checkInputValue();

        });
        function checkInputValue() {
            var count = 0;
            $('input').each(function ( index,value) {
                console.log(value);
                console.log(index);
                if ($(value).val() == 0 && $(value).is(':checked')) {
                    count = count + 1;
                    console.log(count+' input is checked and has 0 value');
                }

            });
            console.log($('input').length);
            if ($('ul').length == count)
                console.log('all first inputs are checked and has 0 value')
        }
    </script>
```